# How should i wait for an input from child process with FIFO

Tags: c, fork, pipe, fifo

I am having a trouble using fifos, i want the parent to create 2 fifos and wait for child to write its user entered date, time and system date and time along with uid to fifo 1 and once it has received this parent has to then opens a log file and writes the contents to log file and fifo2 as well. and the child will read the fifo2 and display the result

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<time.h>
int main()  
{
    int pid;
    char buff[64];
    int ret,ret2;
    FILE *cfp;
    char fifoName[]="/tmp/testfifo23";
    char fifoName2[]="/tmp/testfifo22";
    FILE *cfp2;
    FILE *pfp2;
    char array[36],bufftime[36],buffread[64];
    FILE *pfp,*pfp2;


    //Time Calculation

    time_t rawtime;

    time (&rawtime);
    struct tm  *timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
    strftime(array, sizeof(array)-1, "%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S", timeinfo);

    //

    if((pid=fork())>=0)
    {
        if(pid==0) //child Process
        {

            ret2 = mknod(fifoName, S_IFIFO | 0600, 0);

            if(ret < 0)
            {
                printf("Unable to create fifos");
                exit(0);
            }
            ret2 = mknod(fifoName2, S_IFIFO | 0600, 0);

            if(ret2 < 0)
            {
                printf("Unable to create fifos");
                exit(0);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            sleep(3);
            printf("Enter The date");

            if((fgets(buff,8,stdin)!=NULL))
            {
                printf("Job done %s",buff);
            }  
            printf("\n Enter The time");
            if((fgets(bufftime,8,stdin)!=NULL))
            {

                printf("\nJob done %s",bufftime);
            }

            cfp = fopen(fifoName,"w");
            if(cfp == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to open fifo for writing");
                exit(0);
            }
            ret=fprintf(cfp,"%s %s %s %u",buff,bufftime,array,getuid());
            // fflush(cfp);
            unlink(fifoName);
            //close(fifoName);
            cfp2= fopen(fifoName2,"r");

            if(cfp2 == NULL)
            { 
                printf("Unable to open fifo for reading");
                exit(0);
            }
            ret=fscanf(cfp2,"%s",&buffread);
            if(ret < 0)
                printf("Error reading from named pipe");
            fclose(cfp2);
            printf("%s",buffread);
            unlink(fifoName); /* Delete the created fifo */
            unlink(fifoName2);
            exit(0);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error Occured");

        }


        return 0;
    }
    // Enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have submitted, the child process only opens two named pipes and exists. If you indent your code properly you will realise the problem. Also you would like to use "pipe()" for such application.